# Подскажите какой наилучший вариант отображения "Опыта" в текстовой telegram-игре (pytelegrambotapi)

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

*Сразу же оговорюсь не обессудьте за вероятно глупый вопрос ибо обучаюсь и стараюсь гуглить все возможное, при отсутствии результата задаю вопрос здесь.*

Задача состоит в следующем: пытаюсь создать telegram-игру на python(pytelegrambotapi) в которой будет персонаж, соответственно он будет иметь параметры. Один из логичных параметров для продвижения персонажа является, например, уровень и **опыт**. Если с уровнем вопросов не возникает особо, результат его отображения прост: "Уровень: 1", то как быть с опытом, где есть цель выводить вот такой вид:

Опыт: 1/10 на первом уровне, 1/12 на втором уровне и т.д. переменная копится и обнуляется при получении уровня.

Моего мышления хватает лишь на то, чтобы сделать в базе данных столбец. При выводе в bot.send_message просто отправлять его значение и через слэш выводить переменную, которая будет накапливаться в цикле (10,12,14 и т.д.). И дальше условиями задать обнуление при получении нужных значений, то есть если столбец опыта достиг значения 10, то уровень поднимается, а опыт становится равным 0.

Правильно ли использовать такой подход? Или вообще это все можно сделать в базе данных, задавая определенные параметры столбцу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прогресс персонажа:

- `Вариант 1` Постоянный рейт — т.е. всегда 1000 XP на уровень
- `Вариант 2` Арифметическая прогрессия — 1000 XP + 100 * N на уровень
- `Вариант 3` Геометрическая прогрессия — 1000XP * (1.1)N

Прогресс XP, получаемый за выполнение игровых задач

1. `Постоянный` — время, затраченное на достижение нового уровня, всегда одинаковое
2. `Уменьшающийся` — чем выше уровень, тем больше требуется опыта.
   Пример: пусть кол-во опыта на уровень постоянно: 1000 XP.
   XP убийство моба = 100 * (10 + LVL моба — LVL игрока)/(10 + LVL игрока). На первом уровне нужно убить 10 мобов своего уровня, на десятом — двадцать.

Я советую вам взять любую простой вариант. Скажем, геометрическая прогрессия (формулы известны со школы). И начать экспериментировать с коэффициентами.

[Источник](https://qna.habr.com/answer?answer_id=64323#answers_list_answer)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ответ, обязательно учту информацию. С точки зрения программирования как думаете я правильно описал свои мысли? Имею ввиду с фразы "Моего мышления..."?

Comment: Допустим есть таблица `player` со столбцами `id`, `nickname`, `lvl`. Я бы сделал связанную один-к-одному таблицу  `expirience` со столбцами `id`, `player_id`, `exp_cur`, `exp_limit`.

Comment: При получении опыта, добавлял бы его к `exp_cur`, затем сравнивал с `exp_limit`. Если `exp_cur` >= `exp_limit`, то `exp_cur -= exp_limit`, и новый `exp_limit = <формула расчета нового предела>`. Как то так. А, ну и естественно не забыть `lvl +=1`.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @EugeneKokorin отметь, пожалуйста, ответ. Если он помог решить проблему. Спасибо.